# How to do a http request on watch os with urlsession

Tags: swift, watchos, urlsession

I want to do a simple fetch request using swift on watch os but getting two major issues.

I have tried to URLSession.data.task but it fails all the time with "Lost connection to background transfer service". From googling it seems as though the apple watch goes through a background fetch so you have to set it up to run in the background. As soon as I do that, it complains about delegation and I can't find a proper example that isn't about downloading files. I just want a simple fetch...

```
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MySession")
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/courses") else { return }
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url)
    task.resume()
```

Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - are you fetching data when the app is in foreground or background?

Comment: Solved it! It didn't work on the simulator with the beta I was running. But when I built it to my apple watch it worked.

Comment: What did work after you tried on the watch? Were you able to do foreground fetching? And the completion block worked too? No "Lost connection to background transfer service?"

Comment: @Shades - I didn't have to run it in the background so switched to foreground fetching and then deployed on my watch and then it worked. So the issue was trying to run any fetches through a simulator using the latest beta it seems!

Comment: Oh.. Okay, that's good. And bad, of course, since the sim doesn't work properly. I have also had problems with location on the beta. Both on beta 1 and beta 2. It will not give me updated location: `if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse)` will never be true, and even it I remove that it will not fire locationupdate.

Comment: Thanks, I was churning on this exact same problem. Seems still broken in beta 2.